# Azure + Terraform + Grabbing a variable and passing it along

Tags: linux, bash, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hopefully someone can push me in the right direction.

I have a Terraform plan that currently stands up a Linux VM in Azure. I am attempting to run a bash script to install a software client.

It appears the azurerm provider does not support

> user_data

rather it supports

> custom_data

Am I correct in this statement?

That being said, what I am trying to do as well is this.

Reference instance of the software client is setup within a web portal. The web portal creates a token for this reference instance. That token is then used when installing the software client within the Linux VM.

My code for running the bash script is as follows:

```
> custom_data = <<USERDATA
>         #!/bin/bash -xe
>         curl -J -O -L https://app.strongdm.com/releases/cli/linux && unzip sdmcli* && rm -f sdmcli*
>         sudo ./sdm install --relay 
>         USERDATA
```

I get an error however when running terraform apply

> $ terraform apply
>
> Error: expected "custom_data" to be a base64 string, got
> #!/bin/bash -xe
> curl -J -O -L https://app.strongdm.com/releases/cli/linux && unzip sdmcli* && rm -f sdmcli*
> sudo ./sdm install --relay

Here are my questions:

1. Would I use something like a key vault to hold that token and then
   pull it when the bash script runs?
2. Is there a better way of passing
   that token?
3. Can you pass things of that nature in terraform like
   variables?
4. Am I trying to run my bash script in the correct place?

The bash script is being run within the

> resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "tfssh1" {

block of code.

****UPDATE****

1. Log into Admin UI
2. Create a new instance - Token is generated. Copy this token and save it somewhere.
3. Run install on Linux VM
4. Installation prompts for token saved earlier
5. Token is input
6. Installation completes
7. Admin UI now knows this server matches this instance

I just found this within the provider

```
output "gateway_token" {
  value = sdm_node.my_gateway.gateway[0].token
  sensitive = true
}
```

That is outputting the token in question. I should be able to grab that within my bash script. Now I just need to figure out the correct way to run said bash script through terraform.

Comment: Can you run the bash script and attain the token before the terraform plan/apply?

Comment: The token that I am reaching for is generated elsewhere.

Ill update the original question with the process of how things should work.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the various Azure specifics here to give a complete answer, but I did want to note that Terraform has a function [`base64decode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/base64encode.html) which can encode a string using base64, which might help to get past that _specific_ error message, though it might not address the root problem.

Comment: Thanks Martin  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use base64encode

```
custom_data = base64encode(data.local_file.cloudinit.content)

data "local_file" "cloudinit" {
 filename = "${path.module}/cloud-init.conf"
}
```